# When does a C code interrupt in event driven programming mode ？

Tags: c, linux, libevent

I'm new to c, and event driven programming.

We are using **libevent to develop**

1. how does interrupt work, and when does it happen?
2. Will it interrupt in the middle of a function, or does it always
   interrupt in the end of a function?

for example,

```
extern int arr[100];

void some_func1() {
    int flag;
    // do something to change flag
    if(flag == 0) {
        update1(arr);
    }else if(flag == 1) {
        update2(arr);
    }
}

void some_func2() {
    // print something based on arr
}
```

`some_func1` will be called when `event1` happens, and `some_func2` will be called 
 if `event2` happens.

case 1.
First `event1` occurs then `some_func1` be called and finished, so `arr` is updated correctly, then `event2` occurs, and print is ok

case 2.
First `event1` occurs then `some_func1` be called, and in the middle of it, another `event1` is called, then `arr` is messed up.

3. Will case 2 happen? Is it possible to make some_func1 an atomic
   function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> ### Dispatching events.
>
> Finally, you call **event_base_dispatch()** to loop and dispatch events. You can also use **event_base_loop()** for more fine-grained control.
>
> Currently, only one thread can be dispatching a given **event_base** at a time. If you want to run events in multiple threads at once, you can either have a single **event_base** whose events add work to a work queue, or you can create multiple **event_base** objects.

So, if you've got one thread and one **event_base** then **event_base_dispatch()/event_base_loop()** in this thread call handler functions one by one.

If you've got two threads and two **event_base** (one in each thread) then they work independently. The first **event_base** handles its events one by one in the first thread; the second **event_base** handles its events one by one in the second thread.

(I haven't used libevent, but that's how generally the event loops work)